# Why is $\frac{\sinh(t)+i}{\cosh(t)}$ an arc-length parametrization of the circle

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

This came up on page 40 of Hubbard's *Teichmuller Theory* (Vol 1), in the context of parametrizing geodesics in the upper half.

Where it is essentially implied that 
$$\frac{\sinh(t)+i}{\cosh(t)}$$
is an arc-length parametrization of the unit circle.

**This is my first time seeing such a parametrization and I was wondering there was a (preferably visual or geometric) way to see this.**

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title to match the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least the first part of the following argument is geometric.

Here are two facts about the [Poincaré half-plane model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model) with $d$ denoting the metric:

1. if $x$ and $y$ are positive reals, $d(ix, iy) = |\ln(x) - \ln(y)|$
2. The metric is invariant under linear fractional transformations with real coefficients.

If you don't know these facts, see the Wikipedia link above for 1 (which is easy to prove once you know the integral you have to calculate) and see the Wikipedia page on the [Poincaré metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_metric#Metric_and_volume_element_on_the_Poincar%C3%A9_plane) for a proof of 2.

It follows from fact 1 that we can define an arc-length parametrization of the upper half of the imaginary axis by:
$$
u(t) = ie^t
$$
The linear fractional transformation:
$$
f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}
$$
maps $0, i, \infty$ to $-1, i, 1$ in that order. Hence (using fact 2), $f$ is an isometry from the upper half of the imaginary axis to the upper half of the unit circle. It follows that:
$$
v(t) = f(u(t))
$$
gives an arc-length parametrization of the upper half of the unit circle.

The rest of the proof is algebra. For real $t$, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
v(t) &= \frac{ie^t - 1}{ie^t + 1}\\
   &= \frac{(ie^t - 1)(-ie^t + 1)}{e^{2t}+1} \tag{A}\\
   &= \frac{(ie^t - 1)(-i + e^{-t})}{e^t + e^{-t}} \tag{B} \\
   &= \frac{e^t -e^{-t} +2i}{e^t + e^{-t}} \tag{C}\\
   &= \frac{\sinh(t) + i}{\cosh(t)} \tag{D}
\end{align}
$$
where (A) follows by calculating the reciprocal of the denominator, (B) follows by multiplying top and bottom by $e^{-t}$, (C) follows by multiplying out and (D) follows from the definitions of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$.

Comment: I think the metric is preserved when the coefficients of linear fractional transformation are real.

Comment: @user135520: thanks. I forgot to say that, but I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks for the geometric solution!

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\frac{\sinh t+i}{\cosh t}=\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh t}+i\frac{1}{\cosh t}$$

and

$$\left(\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh t}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\cosh t}\right)^2=\frac{\sinh^2t+1}{\cosh^2 t}=1$$

Comment: Alternatively, the squared absolute value of OP’s formula is $\frac{\sinh^2t+1}{\cosh^2t}=1$

Comment: But why is it a parametrisation by arc length?

Comment: @RobArthan it is a parametrization $x(t)+iy(t)$ with $x(t)^2+y(t)^2=1$ that is the equation of the unit circle centered at the origin.

Comment: @RobArthan It should describe the upper half of the unit circle with respect to the x axis except the points $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

Comment: Yes it's a parametrisation. But you haven't shown that it is a parametrisation by **arc length**.

Comment: @gimusi see the tag hyperbolic-geometry. The question is why in the hyperbolic metric the speed of this parametrisation is constant.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I thought that the point was about the fact that the given expression was a parametrization of the unit circle. How is defined ann arch-length parametrization? Could you add your answer about that? Thanks

Comment: @gimusu:  +1 from me for effort! Unfortunately, you were misled by the title of the question into thinking the question was simpler than it actually is. Never miind! Yours was a good answer to the question that was originally stated in  the title. I hope my answer is of interest.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks I’ll take a look to that!

Comment: I should have explained that an arc-length parametrization is simply a parametrization, $t \mapsto u(t)$, such that the length along the arc from $u(x)$ to $u(y)$ is equal to $| x  - y|$ for all $x, y$ in the parameter interval.